# Sync users from GSuite to KeyCloak

Tags: single-sign-on, keycloak, user-management, google-gsuite

We have G-Suite that is used as an SSO for most of our corporate applications, all users are internal users.

but we introduced KeyCloak in order to manage the security for all applications, exposed portals, internal users, as well as all external users.

I need a way to keep syncing the Users from G-Suite to KeyCloak, so KeyCloak will manage all users\groups\permissions for internal and external users.

Also I need to know how I can provision\de-provision users from KeyCloak where it shall be reflected on G suite as well.

Note: OKTA can do that.

Comment: [Google Cloud docs](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/identity/best-practices-for-federating), [Keycloak docs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_user-storage-federation)